# Why do I have to click twice to take effect of :first?

Tags: jquery

I've scripted something like this. There are two buttons to operate between a set of images - next and previous. The class 'active' is to establish div border for currently chosen one, the 'c' class is for divs containing these images. As you can see, I wanted to make the effect of choosing the first img after clicking 'next' in the end of the collection and choosing the last one after clicking 'previous' when the beginning is clicked. 'Else' for 'previous' button works perfectly well, but for 'next' button I need to click it twice to start from the first image. After the first click I get an empty window. Does anybody know why is that happening? I've checked if I had some empty divs with .c class, but no, there's not such one. What can be important is that all image divs are inside a parent div with such css:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
.child {
    /* percent per item in row. 
    18% = limit to 5 per row. */
    font-size: 15px; color: black;
    flex: 1 0 18%;
    height: 150px;
  }
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.next').click(function(){
    if ($('.active').next('.c').length) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
                    .next('.c')
                    .addClass('active');
        $('.active img:first').trigger('click');
    }
    else {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
                    $('div.c:first')
                    .addClass('active');
        $('.active img:first').trigger('click');
    }
  });
        $('.next').click(function(){
        $('.paste').empty();
        $('.active').clone().appendTo('.paste');
        });
  $('.previous').click(function(){
    if ($('.active').prev('.c').length) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
                    .prev('.c')
                    .addClass('active');
        $('.active img:first').trigger('click');
    }
else {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
                    $('div.c:last')
                    .addClass('active');
        $('.active img:first').trigger('click');
    }
  });
        $('.previous').click(function(){
        $('.paste').empty();
        $('.active').clone().appendTo('.paste');
        });
});
```

```
<p style="font-size: 20px; color:blue"><b>Choose a station:</b></p>
<p style="font-size: 14px; color:black"><b>Click on logos</b></p><br>
<div class="parent" style="font-weight: bold;">
<div class="child c PL">Radio RMF24<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r1" src="r1.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">Radio TOK FM<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r2" src="r2.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">Nocne Radio<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r3" src="r3.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">Enklawa.net<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r4" src="r4.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c US">KDDL Cattle Country<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r5" src="r5.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c NO">P10 Country<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r6" src="r6.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">Radio Kaszëbë<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r7" src="r7.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">Radio 7<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r8" src="r8.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">Nowy Świat<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r9" src="r9.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">Radio 357<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r10" src="r10.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">Radio Plus<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r11" src="r11.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">MeloRadio<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r12" src="r12.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">PR Kierowców<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r13" src="r13.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">Złote Przeboje<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r14" src="r14.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">PR Olsztyn<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r15" src="r15.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">PR Warmii i Mazur<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r16" src="r16.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">Radio MORS<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r17" src="r17.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">NiUS Radio<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r18" src="r18.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
<div class="child c PL">Radio Zamek Nadaje<br><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="r r19" src="r19.png" style="height:50px"></a><br>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="b1" onclick="myFunction()">Show/Hide Players
</button>
<br><br>
<div id="p1">
<div class="p">
<audio class="r r1 PL" src="https://rs103-krk-cyfronet.rmfstream.pl/RMF24" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r2 PL" src="https://radiostream.pl/tuba10-1.mp3" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r3 PL" src="https://c13.radioboss.fm:18296/stream" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r4 PL" src="https://c13.radioboss.fm:18296/stream" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r5 US" src="http://stream.affordablestreaming.com:8000/KDDL.mp3" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r6 NO" src="https://p10.p4groupaudio.com/P10_MM" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r7 PL" src="http://stream3.nadaje.com:8048/;0872561763972044stream.nsv" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r8 PL" src="https://stream.radio7.pl/radio7.mp3" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r9 PL" src="https://n08a-eu.rcs.revma.com/ypqt40u0x1zuv" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r10 PL" src="https://n08a-eu.rcs.revma.com/ye5kghkgcm0uv" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r11 PL" src="https://pl03.cdn.eurozet.pl/plu-gdn.mp3" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r12 PL" src="https://n-16-7.dcs.redcdn.pl/sc/o2/Eurozet/live/meloradio.livx?audio=5" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r13 PL" src="http://stream3.polskieradio.pl:8968/;&type=aac" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r14 PL" src="https://radiostream.pl/tuba9-1.mp3" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r15 PL" src="http://rostr1.radioolsztyn.pl:8000/RO" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r16 PL" src="http://rostr1.radioolsztyn.pl:8300/RWiM" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r17 PL" src="http://streaming.task.gda.pl:8000/mors" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r18 PL" src="https://nius.out.airtime.pro/nius_a" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
<audio class="r r19 PL" src="https://streaming.radio.co/s65cef3a93/listen" controls preload="none" style="visibility: visible"></audio>
</div></div>
```

Well, actually it's not such a big deal, but I just die from curiosity, what can cause this need of clicking twice to get to the first one.

EDIT: Html added

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Add your HTML as well. There is a stack snippet tool you can use to create a runable example in your question. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Post html part plz !

Comment: I've added it right now, the part that could be involved.

Comment: cant find your next class element in your html.

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next round">&#8250;</a><br>

CSS: 
.previous {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.next {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}